# Accomplishment vs. Achievement in résumé/CV application

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, writing-style

I'm curious to know which word is more suitable for the résumé/CV context: accomplishment or achievement?

For instance:

- My accomplishments on this job positions are…
- Key achievements are…

Comment: Oddly enough, _accomplishment_ and _achievement_ both have technical semantic definitions, and define varieties of active verb phrases, among other things. An achievement predicate is one that refers to reaching an ending point, like _arrive in  Dublin_; an accomplishment predicate is one that refers to the activity preceding an achievement, plus the achievement at the end, like _travel to Dublin_. They are two of three types of active predicates; the third is an active predicate, which refers only to an activity, and not to its completion, like _travel_.

Comment: So you can use both -- _accomplishments_ are things where you worked toward a goal and achieved it, and _achievements_ are things like awards that you couldn't anticipate but which marked your ascent.  This allows you to be a little humble (hard to manage in a CV) by distinguishing things you aimed for and won from things you happened to pick up in the process.

Answer (score 3):

You accomplish tasks.  You achieve goals.  You cannot accomplish goals or achieve tasks.

Accomplishments are tasks that you carried out successfully.

Achievements are goals that you reached.